# mysql create view with mysql query that contains variable

Tags: mysql, variables, view

I have the below syntax that I want to use to create a MySQL view:

```
create view `ViewName` as (select
              v_starting.callingname,
              v_starting.geofence,
              v_starting.`updatetime`,
              @lastGroup := @lastGroup + if( @lastAddress = v_starting.geofence 
                                         AND @lastVehicle = v_starting.callingname, 0, 1 ) as GroupSeq,
              @lastVehicle := v_starting.callingname as justVarVehicleChange,
              @lastAddress := v_starting.geofence as justVarAddressChange
           from
              v_starting,
              ( select @lastVehicle := '',
                       @lastAddress := '',
                       @lastGroup := 0 ) SQLVars

           order by
              v_starting.`updatetime` )
```

This fails with error:

```
#1351 - View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter
```

How can I get around this? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented under [`CREATE VIEW` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-view.html):

> A view definition is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - The [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) statement cannot refer to system or user variables.

Answer (score 1):

Think you would need to do this using a subselect to count the records.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT v_starting.callingname,
              v_starting.geofence,
              v_starting.`updatetime`,
              Sub1.PrevRecCount ASGroupSeq
FROM v_starting
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.updatetime, COUNT(DISTINCT b.callingname, b.geofence ) AS PrevRecCount
            FROM v_starting a 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN v_starting b
            ON a.updatetime > b.updatetime
            AND a.callingname != b.callingname
            AND a.geofence != b.geofence
            GROUP BY a.updatetime) Sub1
```

Not 100% sure about this as I am dubious about how you are ordering things to get your count presently.

Answer (score 0):

for variable using, try to use a stored procedure or a custom function